# Install msvcr80d.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

For reasons beyond my control, an app I am working on deploying needs to use the **debug** version of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 library.  I tried to register the msvcr80d.dll with regsvr32.exe and it fails.  Is there a work around to get the debug libraries to register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the visual studio [run time library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(VS.80).aspx) debug version. besides being non optimized this dll contains additional code to detected various run time errors.   you should not use that for distribution, in addition to being slower your application might display all sorts of ungainly debug message boxes.   skip the shortcut and  recompile a release version.

This dll do not export DllRegisterServer and so cannot (and should not) be registered with regsvr32

Answer (score 3):

They shouldn't be registered, and the debug version isn't redistributable. It's best to fix the build of your project to get rid of the debug build, because you can't deploy it this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you install VC++ 2005 Express edition on each target PC that should include the non-redistributable DLLs.  Then maybe you can deploy your app on those PCs.